# Notes Maifile RichText signature indentation

Tags: lotus-notes

A customer of mine is irritated by the alignment of the Rich Text signature one can define in the 9.0.1 IBM Mail Template.

In this use case, I have a two-column, one-row table, the first cell containing an image (the logo), the second cell containing the usual signature information.

The table gets pasted in the memo form with a small indent of about 1/2 inch.

I've tried modifying the table margins, but no bananas, and trying to display the ruler in the Preferences pane also does not work.

Karl-Henry Martinsson [reports](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/95754421e01c567d85257ab0006c1b11?OpenDocument) that using the HTML-solution creates no indentation (I can confirm that), but embeded images don't work apart from a href to an external source, obviously.

I know that Crossware would solve all this but the customer is not interested in third-party installations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And with an embedded Base64-encoded image? See http://www.bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html

Comment: Hi there, This should be user-modifyable from 'normal' users. It would be possible, but I thought End-users would perhaps be able to input some sort of HTML into the system, but wouldn't be able to do a Base-64 conversion.

Comment: I bet there is  an online server that converts any image into a base64 encoded string... but I agree with you that the average user wouldn't be very comfortable with the procedure. A good description and a company example may just be what they need. For me, changing the mail template is close to a mortal sin, to be avoided at all costs. Never say never, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for the problem I mentioned above.

The issue centers around the fact that the source richtext field, Signature_Rich on the profile document (CalendarProfile), is itself part of a table and thus inherits some padding and margin information which the user cannot modify.

I worked around this by creating another profile form, which I called 'CalendarProfile1', which is just a form with a richtext field called Signature_Rich.

I then hacked the CoreEmailClasses_de-DE (your localization will obviously vary), Sub InsertSignature:

```
        script  = |
                        Const msgTxt = "Diese Datei enthält einen oder mehrere Kontakte. Doppelklicken Sie in Notes auf den Anhang, " &_
                        "um die Daten zur Anwendung 'Kontakte' hinzuzufügen. In anderen Mail-Systemen müssen Sie die Datei möglicherweise "&_  
                        "auf Ihrem Desktop speichern und anschließend in die Anwendung 'Kontakte' importieren."

                        Dim s As New NotesSession
                        Dim db As NotesDatabase
                        Dim profileDoc As NotesDocument
                        Dim wksp As New NotesUIWorkspace
                        Dim uiDoc As NotesUIDocument

                        Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
                        Set profileDoc = db.GetProfileDocument("CalendarProfile1")
                        Set uiDoc = wksp.CurrentDocument
                        If profileDoc.HasItem("Signature_Rich") Then
                            If uidoc.Document.HasItem("$VAttach") Then  
                                Call uidoc.FieldSetText("body", msgTxt + Chr(10) + Chr(10))         
                            End If  
                            Call uiDoc.ImportItem(profileDoc, "Signature_Rich") 
                        End If  
                    |
```

note how IBM solves the problem of 'how do I append a rich text field to another one in an UIDocument that hasn't been saved' by executing a script defined as text and using the undocumented function NotesUIDocument.ImportField.

It's a big hack, and ugly, but might be useful for anyone who has a mandate for a 'quick and dirty' repsonse.

Comment: And my suggestion to use an embedded Base64-encoded image (in HTML)? :-|

Comment: Hi D.Bugger, that was a technically feasible solution, but got rejected because the users needed a really simple solution.